# SQL Full text Search with phrases, prefix_term on multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, full-text-search, sql-server-2014

My application is storing Names of Customers in 3 Columns, but the search triggered using a single parameter. I am trying to implement a FULLTEXT Search to effectively search in this customer database.

I am looking for the name

> RIMA HUSSEIN

I used the following TSQL to search with the starting word.

```
SELECT 
    REM_ID, REM_FNAME, REM_MNAME, REM_LNAME 
FROM 
    dbo.tblM_REMMASTER 
WHERE 
    CONTAINS((REM_FNAME , REM_MNAME, REM_LNAME) ,'"RIMA*"')
```

The query works as expected providing me with good search result.

[image]

This scenario does not provide me with any result if I provide an updated query with phrases.

Sample test queries executed to try and resolve the scenario.

```
SELECT 
    REM_ID, REM_FNAME, REM_MNAME, REM_LNAME 
FROM 
    dbo.tblM_REMMASTER 
WHERE 
    CONTAINS((REM_FNAME , REM_MNAME, REM_LNAME), '"rima*" AND "*hussein"') 

SELECT 
    REM_ID, REM_FNAME, REM_MNAME, REM_LNAME  
FROM 
    dbo.tblM_REMMASTER 
WHERE 
   CONTAINS(REM_FNAME  ,'"RIMA HUSSEIN"')

SELECT 
    REM_ID, REM_FNAME, REM_MNAME, REM_LNAME 
FROM 
    dbo.tblM_REMMASTER 
WHERE 
    CONTAINS((REM_FNAME , REM_MNAME, REM_LNAME)  ,'NEAR ((RIMA,HUSSEIN),MAX,TRUE)')
```

Has anyone faces this issue before or what kind of solution logic can be implemented under this specific scenario ?

Sample query tested in the live environment without fulltext:

```
SET @NAME=N'RIMAHUSSEIN'

SELECT  
    REM_ID, REM_FNAME, REM_MNAME, REM_LNAME 
FROM 
    dbo.tblM_REMMASTER WITH (READPAST) 
WHERE
    ((LTRIM(RTRIM(REM_FNAME)) +  LTRIM(RTRIM(REM_MNAME)) + LTRIM(RTRIM(REM_LNAME)) LIKE '%' + @NAME + '%'))
```

Comment: Can you separate out the first, middle, and last components of the name input and use `LIKE` on each component?

Comment: Show exactly what each of this conditions should do. You can try using LIKE.

Answer (score 3):

We have application that must search in almost every column in a table, so we create a view `WITH SCHEMABINDING` and `CLUSTERED INDEX` with structure like this:

```
CREATE VIEW search_view
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT  id,
        column1 + ' ' + column2 + etc as search_text
FROM table

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX ci_id ON search_view (id);
```

And put full text index on `search_text` column.
Then we just:

```
SELECT ...
FROM table t
INNER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(search_view, search_text, '"word1*" AND "word2*" ... ') AS sv
    ON t.ID = sv.ID
```

Comment: This is the most suitable answer, But I am worried about the slowness. Could it occur while creating views ? The table in most cases would be having nearly 15 - 20 Million on average case.

Comment: On creation - no, when using view - there may be issues. For example in our view we concatinate over 10 columns, most of them are `nvarchar(max)` and row count ~150k and is incrising every day (+100-200 rows per day). Users make ~400 request per day. The average response time for querys is ~500 miliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try..

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.tblM_REMMASTER WHERE CONTAINS((REM_FNAME,REM_MNAME, REM_LNAME) ,'"RIMA*"') 
AND  CONTAINS((REM_FNAME , REM_MNAME, REM_LNAME), '"*hussein"')
```

Comment: OR Returns a huge record in the resultset, but AND provides accurate results but does not completely solve the issue when there is Three words in the search clause. Also the Query is passed from the application in a single variable as shown in the query without using the Full-Text